# StreamWriter fails to recognize c:\ in compact .net 2.0

Tags: c#, compact-framework, compact-framework2.0

I have the following code

```
        using (var str = new StreamWriter(newFileName))
        {
            foreach (Entry entry in this.Entries)
            {
                str.WriteLine(
                    String.Format(
                        @"""{0}"";{1:yyyy-dd-MMThh:mm:ss};""none"""
                        , entry.Data
                        , entry.Date
                    )
                );
            }
        }
```

where `newFileName = @"C:\asln.csv"`

This codes works fine on .Net Framework 2.0 but fails miserably on Compact 2.0.

It throws an error `"Could not find a part of the path '\\C:\\asln.csv'."`

So, for some reason the path is perpended with `\\`.

How to work around that?

Comment: Are you trying to access the c:\ of the computer from windowsCe device? If so it is not possible from the file API as far as I know.

Answer (score 4):

c:\ does not exist in compact framework (windows ce). All paths need to start with a backslash (\)

So if it is in the root folder the path should be \asln.csv. But make sure that the file is actually in the root. Different devices have different rules, and putting the file in the root is probably not going to work on all devices.

Comment: Is there any way to put it in a folder I'm sure will be ok?

Comment: you can put it in the folder your program is running from: System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase; And remember that the system folder might be different places. \windows might be ROM storage, and \programfiles might be larger and slower flash storage. And then you have the mmc card where your file is supposed to be and then someone changed cards...

Comment: CodeBase (as well as Location) doesn't exists in Compact 2.0 for Smart Devices.

Comment: sorry framework 1 I think... This is framwork 2,0 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229654(v=vs.80).aspx

Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetModules()[0].FullyQualifiedName);